# mixing mininclusive and enumeration in xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml element whose range of value is (*intrinsically*) 1-20 so I can use:
`minInclusive=1` and `maxInclusive=20` to restrict the intrinsic set.

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
   <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
   <xs:maxInclusive value="20"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

However, I also want to be able to set an *extrinsic* value of -4 which has the specific meaning: «Unknown»

Is this possible? That is: 1-20 & -4 (not -4-20).

I thought I might be able to get away with adding enumeration value= -4 but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
   <xs:enumeration value="-4"/>
   <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
   <xs:maxInclusive value="20"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need here is an [`xs:union`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dt-union), which will allow you to join the two restrictions types together, e.g.

```
<xs:simpleType name="numbersOnetoTwenty">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
     <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
     <xs:maxInclusive value="20"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="justMinusFour">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
     <xs:enumeration value="-4"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="mySet">
  <xs:union memberTypes="numbersOnetoTwenty justMinusFour" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart,  after doing some more research, that seems to be the way to go.  (If you have sufficient control over the XML spec - not always the case).